# How to create a patch file for new source code

Tags: patch

I am trying to do a mini code review for *new* source code that I have in a folder.  The code is not in any kind of version control.  Is it possible to create a patch file from this so I can post it for review?

Every incantation of patch I've seen fits an oldCode/newCode pattern.

Comment: What are you patching **against**? If you're making changes to a file, save it as a new file and then run `patch` from there.

Comment: @MattDMo, I'm not patching against anything.  All of the sources are new

Comment: Let me provide more context.  When I put the code up for review, all of the files will show up as new source

Comment: If they are new files, they are new files; there is no (useful) difference to before (unless you diff against /dev/null, but that is rather pointless anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and given that you want to include your new `src` directory in the patch, you could call `diff -Naur` with a non-existent (or empty) directory as the first parameter:

```
diff -Naur nonexistent src > src.patch
```

However, when using this patch file, for example with `patch -p0 < src.patch`, the files will be extracted in a directory named "nonexistent".

To make it easier for the receiver, perhaps you could temporarily rename your `src` dir to something else, for example:

```
mv src src-real
diff -Naur src src-real > src.patch
mv src-real src
```

I don't know if there is a better way...

Comment: thanks for your response.  This didn't quite work for me.  I get:
diff -u /dev/null src/ > code.patch 
diff: src/null: No such file or directory

Comment: diff -Naur src2/ src > /tmp/mywork.patch that worked after I created an empty src2 directory.  Accepting your answer

Comment: @AmirAfghani I improved my answer. See my last word of caution, about what happens when using such patch file. And maybe unaccept the answer for a while, maybe others will answer it better. You can accept a few days later if it still makes sense.